# EmguCV - how to specify jpeg quality when saving image?

Tags: c#, image-processing, opencv, emgucv

I save jpeg image using the following C# [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/) code:

```
Emgu.CV.Image<Gray, byte> image
...
image.Save("imageName.jpg");
```

But image is stored in extremally low quality (1 color square per 8x8 pixels).

When I save bmp all are ok:

```
Emgu.CV.Image<Gray, byte> image
...
image.Save("imageName.bmp");
```

How to increase jpeg quality when using `Emgu.Cv.Image.Save` or should I call other function?
Why is default quality so low?

Tried to ask on [EmguCV forum](http://www.emgu.com/forum/), but it is unreachable.

Comment: Hi, on behalf of EMGU I apologise for the website being down but I'm always trolling here and codeproject for any questions that I can help with. Cheers

Comment: @Chris Thanks a lot. Now I know to whom I can ask. Suggest stable work of the site!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EMGU only has image.Save(filename) therefore you have to use the .Net method of saving the image. This code is derived from [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing). I separated the code for ease this code opens a file then attempts to save it. This is the function you interested in **saveJpeg(SaveFile.FileName, img.ToBitmap(), 100);**.  Based on the function saveJpeg(string path, Bitmap img, long quality).

```
open.Filter = "Image Files (*.tif; *.dcm; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp)|*.tif; *.dcm; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp";
if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Image<Bgr, Byte> img = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(open.FileName);
    SaveFileDialog SaveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
    if (SaveFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        saveJpeg(SaveFile.FileName, img.ToBitmap(), 100);
    }
}
```

Now to get the code for that function comes from the following you can copy and paste this into your project don't forget the using statement at the top of your code.

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

private void saveJpeg(string path, Bitmap img, long quality)
{
    // Encoder parameter for image quality

    EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);

    // Jpeg image codec
    ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = this.getEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");

    if (jpegCodec == null)
    return;

    EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
    encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;

    img.Save(path, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
}

private ImageCodecInfo getEncoderInfo(string mimeType)
{
    // Get image codecs for all image formats
    ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();

    // Find the correct image codec
    for (int i = 0; i < codecs.Length; i++)
    if (codecs[i].MimeType == mimeType)
    return codecs[i];
    return null;
}
```

This is the best method for EMGU if you get stuck let me know.

Hope this Helps,

Chris

Comment: Seems suitable for me. thanks. Anyway something strange happened with EmguCV - why does it save jpeg with so low quality? I can't realize.

Comment: I can't specify exactly it's not the first time I've come across such poor image saving functions in fact some costly MVS systems use the same compression quality. I will bring up the matter however it might not make it into a new release as this method is rather platform specific. Glad it helped though, Cheers

Comment: I have found how to reproduce so strange behavior. If application is run under VS2010 and bin directory contain highgui210d.dll the problem appears, if I delete highgui210d.dll all works fine...

Answer (score 5):

Building on Chris's answer if anyone is interested here is a simple extention;

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

public static class EmguImageSave
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Save a jpeg image with a specified quality
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">Name of the file to which to save the image</param>
    /// <param name="quality">Byte that specifies JPEG Quality of the image encoder</param>
    public static void Save( this Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, Byte> img, string filename, double quality )
    {
        var encoderParams = new EncoderParameters( 1 );
        encoderParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(
            System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality,
            (long)quality
            );

        var jpegCodec = (from codec in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
                         where codec.MimeType == "image/jpeg"
                         select codec).Single();

        img.Bitmap.Save( filename, jpegCodec, encoderParams );
    }
}
```

Usage;

```
var fname = 0;
while( true )
{
    try
    {
        var img = capture.QueryFrame();
        img.Save( String.Format( @"c:\rec\{0}.jpg", ++fname), 100 );
    } catch( Exception ) { break; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I did with Emgu CV:

```
CvInvoke.Imwrite(path, cvImage, new KeyValuePair<ImwriteFlags, int> (ImwriteFlags.JpegQuality, quality));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. And why don't you use the old and good OpenCV http://opencv.itseez.com doc?

```
int quality = 100; // 0 - low, 100 - best
image.Save("imageName.bmp", CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, quality);
```

Comment: Sorry but, this is not possible with EMGU and the OpenCV reference is not applicable.