# Image size got bigger when trying to reduce its size

Tags: c#, image-resizing

I am trying to resize a pic of format jpg, reduce it's resolution in order for it to be smaller when I download it to the site HTML. Using the tutorial in the link:
[image resizing tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing)

I managed to resize the resolution including cropping when needed. My problem is that actual size of the image got bigger instead of smaller as I expected.

Any ideas please?

Comment: By "actual size" do you mean in terms of bytes or pixels?

Comment: In the past I have used this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfWeek11ImageResizerEnablesCleanClearImageResizingInASPNET.aspx

Comment: @Jon Skeet By actual size I mean bytes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a JPEG image file is getting bigger when you are reducing the dimensions, it's because you are saving it with a higher quality setting than the original.

Comment: I tried playing with the InterpolationMode property but no matter what the file keeps getting bigger. one thing to mention is that the jpg file I am trying to resize is 5kb (which result in a 27 kb file), which probably means it was already compressed before.

Comment: @mashtagidi: You should use `InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic` to get the image that compresses best. Using `NearestNeighbor` will make most images harder to compress. If the original image is only 5 kb, and it's large enough that you want to make it smaller, then it is probably saved with a quite low quality setting. Lower the quality setting when you save your file until you get the file size that you want, and see if the image quality is acceptable.

Comment: thank you. "Lower the quality setting when you save your file". How can I control it? I use the save() function which is a built in, in the Image class.

Comment: @mashtagidi: The built in method uses the highest quality setting (100) unless you specify encoder parameters with a different setting. Use the saveJpeg method from the tutorial that you linked to.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite normal when you use a compressed image format like jpeg.  It is caused by the filter you selected when you reduced the image size.  A default selection for the Graphics class, for example, is InterpolationMode.Bilinear.  Which does a pretty nice job of making a good looking shrunk version of the image.  But at a cost of adding a lot of extra colors to the image due to the filtering algorithm.  The resulting image won't compress as well as the original and can in fact require more storage.

You'd have to pick a lower quality filter to avoid this, like InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor.  Yes, won't look nearly as good.  In general you should avoid re-compressing an image that was already compressed in a lossy format like jpeg.

Comment: When you say I should avoid re-compressing an image that was already compressed you assume what I am trying to compress was already compressed? or is that a general statement?

Comment: That was the most logical conclusion.  Not sure why you are not telling us what kind of image format you are using, no reason to keep it a secret.

Comment: JPEG is not using indexed colors, so using InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor to keep it from creating new colors won't make it compress better, rather the opposite.

Comment: @Hans Passant of course it's no secret :). Usually the images I am trying to re-size are of format jpg or jpeg.

Comment: Well, it is a jpeg and the sample code uses InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic so everything in my answer fits.  Tinker with the InterpolationMode property to see the effect on the resulting image.

Comment: @Hans Passant "In general you should avoid re-compressing an image that was already compressed in a lossy format like jpeg" can you explain why? I am trying to resize a jpg file (5kb) and the result is 27 kb no matter which InterpolationMode I use.

Comment: ok I managed to solve it by using the quality parameter in the save function like so: [save function][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914243/emgucv-how-to-specify-jpeg-quality-when-saving-image


thank you :)