# Image size gets bigger when trying to reduce its size

Tags: c#, image-resizing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Image size got bigger when trying to reduce its size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228050/image-size-got-bigger-when-trying-to-reduce-its-size)

What I am trying to resize is a `.jpg` file (5kb) and the result is 27kb, no matter which InterpolationMode I use. judging from it's size The original file probably was already compressed before. The aim was to reduce it's resolution in order for it to be smaller when I add it to my site. I am using this tutorial:
[Image resizing tutorial.](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing)

I managed to resize the resolution including cropping. My problem is that actual size of the image got bigger instead of smaller as I expected.

Any ideas please?

Comment: why are you asking the same question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228050/image-size-got-bigger-when-trying-to-reduce-its-size

Comment: @MaciekTalaska my problem is not yet resolve so what would you do if you were me?

Comment: I would improve my last question, add some more information to it. Share with others all those things that you've tried since it appeared on SO. Just think about it: what is the point in asking exactly the same question? Is it really going to be of help to anyone? There is a whole section in SO FAQ which focuses on quality of questions and way to improve them. Apart from that... you can always add a bounty to your question, so that someone will be awarded more points for the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adjusting the quality for the parameter you are passing to the `saveJpeg` method instead of just the `InterpolationMode`.

What quality are you currently using?

Comment: I tried playing with the InterpolationMode property but no matter what the file keeps getting bigger. one thing to mention is that the jpg file I am trying to resize is 5kb (which result in a 27 kb file), which probably means it was already compressed before

Comment: what do you mean adjusting the quality besides the InterpolationMode?

Comment: for the method `private void saveJpeg(string path, Bitmap img, long quality)` that you must call to save the jpeg what is the value you pass for the `quality` parameter, adjust that.

Comment: I am calling img.Save() which is a built in function in Image class, and I am passing only a string path to it.